# Ado.Net Fill Grid By Logged in User

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to fill a gridview with records according to the currently logged in user. My stored procedure asks for one parameter, the ID of the user. I want that parameter to be the currently logged in user but i cant figure out how to accomplish this.

My stored Procedure to grab the records:

```
@cnt_ID int 

AS
BEGIN
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vtCursusPlanning.cur_CursusID AS CursusID, dbo.vtCursusPlanning.cur_Omschrijving AS Omschrijving, CONVERT(varchar, 
                      dbo.vtData.dat_Datum, 100) AS Datum, CONVERT(varchar, dbo.vtData.dat_Start, 100) AS DStart, CONVERT(varchar, dbo.vtData.dat_Stop, 100) AS DStop, 
                      dbo.vtContactPersonen.cnt_Initialen AS Username
FROM         dbo.vtData INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vtCursusPlanning ON dbo.vtData.cur_FK = dbo.vtCursusPlanning.cur_CursusID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vtContactPersonen ON dbo.vtCursusPlanning.cnt_FK = dbo.vtContactPersonen.cnt_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vtCursusCursisten ON dbo.vtData.cur_FK = dbo.vtCursusCursisten.cst_fk
WHERE     (dbo.vtContactPersonen.cnt_ID = @cnt_ID) AND (NOT (dbo.vtCursusCursisten.cst_fk IS NULL)) AND (NOT (dbo.vtCursusPlanning.cur_Project IS NULL))
ORDER BY DStart
END
```

And my attempt to fill the gridview with my C# code.

```
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "@cnt_ID" };
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KRIS-Planning"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("spOffice2010Evaluaties", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@cnt_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        comm.Parameters["@cnt_ID"].Value = UserID;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dbErrorLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you cannot get the UserId ? is that your issue ?

Comment: yes! the reason that i cannot retrieve any records is because it says that cnt_ID never gets filled. however i cannot use something like  string UserId = Membership.GetUser(@Cnt_ID).ProviderUserKey.ToString(); because it expects the dbo.asp.net default database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead;

> ```
>  string UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
> ```

Comment: This does in fact grab the currently logged in username. But i sort my stored procedure with the cnt_ID wich is the pirmary key of the table that holds all the Users. The Username i get with this is an nvarchar and the cnt_ID is an int. How do i convert it correctly so it will still grab the records?

Comment: If you have two different fields on your data table with Id(int) and UserId(nvarchar) then you have two options to fix this: 1. In your store procedure first get the Id(int) based on the given UserId and do the rest 2. simply change `dbo.vtContactPersonen.cnt_ID` to `dbo.vtContactPersonen.cnt_USERID` if you have such a field `USERID` in your database table and of course change `@cnt_ID int` to `@cnt_USERID nvarchar(50)`.